# Foreign key not implementing in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to make a table with the given query:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales_order129(
    S_order_no varchar(6) primary key check(S_order_no Like '0%'),
    S_order_date Date,
    client_no varchar(6) foreign key references client_master129(client_no),
    Dely_add varchar(25),
    Salesman_no varchar(6) foreign key references Sales_master129(Salesman_no),
    Dely_type char(1) check(Dely_type in('P','F')) default 'F',
    Billed_yn char(1),
    Dely_date date check(Dely_date>=S_order_date),
    Order_status varchar(10) check(Order_status in('in process','fulfilled','back order','cancelled'))
    );
```

but it is showing the given error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key references client_master129(client_no),
> Dely_add varchar(25),
> Salesm' at line 4

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

you can't use short cuts for froreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE Sales_order129(
     S_order_no varchar(6) primary key check(S_order_no Like '0%'),
     S_order_date Date,
     client_no varchar(6) ,
     foreign key (client_no) references client_master129(client_no),
     Dely_add varchar(25),
     Salesman_no varchar(6) ,
     foreign key (Salesman_no) references Sales_master129(Salesman_no),
     Dely_type char(1) check(Dely_type in('P','F')) default 'F',
     Billed_yn char(1),
     Dely_date date check(Dely_date>=S_order_date),
     Order_status varchar(10) check(Order_status in('in process','fulfilled','back order','cancelled'))
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Default has to come before CHECK

Dely_type char(1) default 'F' check(Dely_type in('P','F')) ,

And you cannot use fk shortcuts see answer by @nbk

if you still have errors please publish your referenced tables including the engine used.